# The code for my navbar does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm a beginner trying to code a navbar in a practice website but I can't get the final product right.

My navbar is supposed to line up horizontally along the top of the page and then be follow the page as you scroll with a black shadow backdrop. Currently when you load the page, the words line up vertically on the right side, and then condense when you scroll. I also have a logo in the top left that shrinks way too small. Finally, when when you shrink the page, a hamburger icon pops up in the top right that is supposed to show you the menu options, however it no longer works. It's like a cycle with this page, I fix one thing and break another. I am doing this just for fun because I'm trying to learn but now I'm getting frustrated, Thanks!

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu i").click(function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("active")
  })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Hairline|Oswald|Raleway&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .5s;
}

nav.black {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

nav.logo {
  float: left;
}

nav .logo img {
  height: 80px;
  transition: .5s;
}

nav.black .logo img {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

nav ul li {
  List-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  Line-height: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .5s;
}

nav.black ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  Line-height: 20px;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #008cff;
}

.responsive-bar {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .responsive-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #262626;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    Left: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .responsive-bar .logo img {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .responsive-bar .menu i {
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    Line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  nav {
    padding: 60px;
  }
  nav.black {
    display: none;
    background: #262626;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 60;
    Left: 0;
    background: #262626;
    float: none;
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul.active {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%
  }
  nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    Line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  height: 1000px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-bar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.png">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <div class="active">
      <li><a href="# ">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#continue">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="main">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: none of your CSS seems to change the default display behaviour of a `li` - perhaps you should address that

Comment: you also put the li inside a div inside ul ... that's not going to work